# Tomcat usando todos os cores

Tags: tomcat, pentaho

bom dia!
Existe alguma configuração a ser feita para o Tomcat utilizar todos os cores existentes na máquina?

Estou perguntando, pois percebi que o tomcat aqui não usa todos os cores.

Abraço,

Answer (score 0):

Segundo este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004244/tomcat-not-using-all-cores-in-high-load-period), a seguinte configuração no compilador permite corrigir esse comportamento:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```